# Text::Xslate returning incorrect value for function call

Tags: perl, catalyst, template-toolkit, html-formhandler, text-xslate

I'm using [Text::Xslate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Xslate) with [HTML::FormHandler](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::FormHandler) (HTML::FormHandler is actually used behind the scenes by [CatalystX::SimpleLogin](https://metacpan.org/pod/CatalystX::SimpleLogin), in case that helps). I'm using Text::Xslate's [TTerse](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Xslate::Syntax::TTerse) syntax and trying to show the errors in my template like so:

```
[% FOR field IN login_form.error_fields %]
    [% FOR error IN field.errors %]
        <p>[% field.label _ ': ' _ error %]</p>
    [% END %]
[% END %]
```

If I just print out

```
[% login_form %]
```

It returns `CatalystX::SimpleLogin::Form::Login=HASH(0x7fbb21722a20)`, which is what I would expect. But then when I call `error_fields` on it, it just returns a `1`. However, when I use [Template::Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) instead of Text::Xslate, this works properly and the errors show. Does anyone know why `error_fields` is returning a number and not an array?